# Str_replace not replacing completely

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
<?php
$str ='[ "spiderman", "xmen", "barbie", "avengers" ]';

$array= str_replace("[", "",$str);
$array= str_replace("]", "",$str);

$array =explode(',',$array);


print_r($array);
```

It is meant to output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  spiderman
    [1] =>  xmen
    [2] =>  barbie
    [3] =>  avengers
)
```

But rather it outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => [ "spiderman"
    [1] =>  "xmen"
    [2] =>  "barbie"
    [3] =>  "avengers" 
)
```

Why didn't it completely replace all instances of `[`?
How do I do it well?
............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with Javascript - please tag your questions appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `json` format. Dont use `str_replace` and `explode` to decode it. You can use `json_decode` to parse.

```
$str ='[ "spiderman", "xmen", "barbie", "avengers" ]';
$arr = json_decode($str);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => spiderman
    [1] => xmen
    [2] => barbie
    [3] => avengers
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is json but the right form for your code is :

```
<?php

$str ='[ "spiderman", "xmen", "barbie", "avengers" ]';

$array= str_replace("[", "",$str);
$array= str_replace("]", "",$array);

$array =explode(',',$array);


print_r($array);
```

And result:

```
Array (
    [0] =>  "spiderman"
    [1] =>  "xmen"
    [2] =>  "barbie"
    [3] =>  "avengers"

)
```